# JavaScript switch not executing

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have this simple JavaScript code. The switch is not executed, for some reason, which is a mystery for me! What stupid error have I made?

```
function hndlEv ( e )
{
    switch ( document.forms[0].zcode.length )
    {
        case 1: document.forms[0].zcode.style.backgroundColor = "ffcc33"; break;
        case 2: document.forms[0].zcode.style.backgroundColor = "ffff33"; break;
        case 3: document.forms[0].zcode.style.backgroundColor = "ccff33"; break;
        case 4: document.forms[0].zcode.style.backgroundColor = "66ff33"; break;
        case 5: document.forms[0].zcode.style.backgroundColor = "00ff33"; break;
    }
}
...
<body onload="setfocus();" onkeypress="hndlEv(event);">
...
<input type="text" name="zcode" size="6" maxlength="6" class="code" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function hndlEv ( e )
{
    switch ( document.forms[0].zcode.value.length )
    {
        case 1: document.forms[0].zcode.style.backgroundColor = "ffcc33"; break;
        case 2: document.forms[0].zcode.style.backgroundColor = "ffff33"; break;
        case 3: document.forms[0].zcode.style.backgroundColor = "ccff33"; break;
        case 4: document.forms[0].zcode.style.backgroundColor = "66ff33"; break;
        case 5: document.forms[0].zcode.style.backgroundColor = "00ff33"; break;

    }
}
```

Try this

Comment: Please, first (at least): `var zcode = document.forms[0].zcode` then ... `zcode.value.length`, etc. It's really hard to see your change to the value being selected upon. (Although for sake of the poster I'd make the select and set a two-step process, and perhaps use a lookup and not a switch...)

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo.  hEv() is not the same as hndlEv().

Comment: Sorry, this too. But the input field still dont change it`s color.